# Detect delete notifications button

Tags: android, notifications, detect

Can I detect in my service when the user has pressed the "delete" button in notification bar to clean icon notification? It is a notification my service previously put there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`deleteIntent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#deleteIntent) on the `Notification` to specify a `PendingIntent` to be invoked when the user clears it.